# HTML anchor tags and react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, html5-history

I have a react + react-router SPA with hash based history, and I've come across a roadblock.

Here's what my URL looks like:

`http://mysite/#/path/:id`

Based on the `id` I retrieve a document asynchronously and display that. The document I retrieve is a pre-cooked HTML document that I `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on a component.

Now, the problem is that the above document may contain named/id anchors to jump to a specific piece on that page.

e.g. `<a href="#2">Check out section 2</a>`

I'd like to rewrite/re-process the HTML on the client side before `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` so that these anchor links work. What's the right way to do this?

PS: I tried using hash-less history, but I have other problems with that (e.g. all `<a>` tags need to be created with `<Link>` now to avoid page reload.

Comment: What is the problem that happens now?

Comment: Using hash based history, the URL on the `<a>` tag points to `http://mysite/#path/:id#2` - which doesn't work (nothing happens on clicking)

Comment: Is the `href` correct though? Does it replace `:id` with the correct id in the link? Or is that the problem?

Comment: You might want to replace all `<a>` tags with `<Link>`, using things like regex.

Comment: @Chris, it does replace id and ends up with an incorrect link - you're right. However, I can perhaps prevent this with some JS. But nevertheless, I still can't make it to work because the browser doesn't seem to handle links like `http://mysite/#path/:id#2`

Comment: So that's the problem then. You need your anchors to point to `http://mysite/#path/123#2` instead of `http://mysite/#path/:id#2`. Kujira was actually correct suggesting to use a regex to find a replace the `:id` with the correct value. This normally wouldn't work, but since using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` takes the html as a string, you could probably do this.

Comment: @Chris, from my experience, in Chrome at least, a link with two hashes doesn't work. Let me know if you observe otherwise.

Comment: @ragebiswas You're right. There can only ever be one hash, I didn't notice there was 2. I believe you'd have to find another solution in that case, unless you use another type of history that isn't hash. (basically `http://mysite/path/123#2`)

Comment: Yeah, looks like using browser history (HTML5 pushState) is the only way, I'll confirm this by tomorrow. Sigh :'(